# Access a typeconverter from invoked class

Tags: c#, invoke, typeconverter

I have an application containing a certain number of custom TypeConverter. They work well when used in the context of XML parsing.

On another side I am invoking class constructors (based on some previously defined XML tag) using the following (that works so far):

```
Type MyClass = TypeDelegator.GetType( FullClassName );               // Get the class type
if( MyClass != null ) {                                              // If we find a matching type
    ConstructorInfo[] CtorInfos = MyClass.GetConstructors();         // Get constructor infos
    if( CtorInfos != null ) {                                        // If we could find a ctor
        if( CtorInfos.Length == 1 ) {                                // We expect 1 Ctor with args
            CtorInfos[0].Invoke( new object[] { CtorArg1, CtorArg2 } ); 
        }
    }
}
```

Now I am trying to reuse the TypeConverter from within the invoked constructor. But it does not seems to work. I have been using the regular GetConverter method:

```
MyType myVar = (MyType)TypeDescriptor.GetConverter( typeof( MyType ) ).ConvertFrom( "1;2;3;4" );
```

The type class is similar to the following:

```
public class MyType {
    private int PrivateField;
    public MyType() { }
    public MyType( String Arg1, Char Arg2 ) { }
    public int Prop1 { get { return ( 4 ); } }
    public int Prop2 { 
        get { return ( PrivateField ); }
        set { PrivateField = value; } 
    }
}
```

Digging into the problem it seems that TypeDescriptor.GetConverter does not find the custom type converter (that are part of the same assembly).

```
var debugVar = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter( typeof( MyType ) );
```

always return a TypeConverter as opposed to an expected "TypeConverterMyType". That make me think "TypeConverterMyType" is not accessible probably because of the invoke.

**[Update]**
It seems that the TypeDescriptor.GetConverter works for enum types but not for class based type. I think I am passing next to an important part of the puzzle... :?

So the question :
1- Is it actually possible to access a custom type converter from an invoked method?
2- Is there a better/smarter way to handle this?
3- I am using .Net 3.5, should I expect the same behaviour if I upgrade to 4.0 or 4.5?

Comment: For the love of god, please STOP using Hungarian Notation!